# How do I get the keys to the sewer?

Tags: stardew-valley

There is a cutscene that indicates that the whale/ghost noise that constantly plays is coming from the sewer, and in order to enter I need to get the key from the museum curator.  However, when I go to visit him, nothing happens.

So **how do I get the keys**?  Do I need to get a certain number of artifacts?  Is it a random reward?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the Stardew Valley [Wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/The_Sewers):

> The Sewers are unlocked by obtaining the Rusty Key after donating 60
>   Artifacts to the Museum. They can be entered either through the sewer
>   cover in the South of Pelican Town or through the grates in the South
>   of Cindersap Forest.
>
> In the Sewers you can catch the Mutant Carp, which is one of the five
>   legendary fish in the game.
>
> Krobus is also located here and sells 'rare' items, including a
>   Stardrop and Iridium Sprinklers.